# Japanese (mozc) does not show up in 22.04

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, ibus, japanese, mozc

I've already uninstalled and reinstalled Japanese in my Language Support, but Japanese (mozc) does not show up. I didn't tried anything else so far besides that. I'm using iBus.

[Keyboard  layout.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYlgR.png)

[Japanese input methods that shows up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vuVX5.png)

Comment: `reboot` 詳しくは[こちら](https://hirooka.pro/ubuntu-22-04-lts-japanese-input-ibus-fcitx-mozc/)

Comment: I have the same problem and rebooting does not solve it.

Answer (score 0):

For some people, it seems that rebooting is enough.

However, for me, I had to remove the `.config/mozc` files from a previous installation with

```
$ rm -rf ~/.config/mozc
```

After doing this, Japanese (Mozc) automatically appeared in the input dropdown menu of the toolbar.